# Strange c pointer issue

Tags: c++

I had this kind of question in a job interview.
This code seems to be very easy:

```
  long a = 1234;
  long &b = a;
```

For me, a and b are the same thing.
But i was asked which expression of the 4 following is the same thing

```
  const *long c = &a;
  const long *d = &a;
  const * long e = &a;
  long *const f = &a;
```

Honestly, i do not understand which of the 4 is the equivalent.

Comment: Two of the pointer definitions are not valid.

Comment: (1) and (3) are the same thing since they are both wrong :) :)

Comment: None of them is the 'same thing' but the fourth option is creating a pointer, pointing to the address of 'a', and because it's a const pointer it cannot be changed to point at any other address, so I guess it is kind of the same thing, even though to get the value you will have to dereference 'f' whereas you won't have to do that with 'b'.

Comment: I would say that a and b in your code may be threat as the same variables. Both are pointing to the same address and both have the same value.
Non of the pointers are the same thing as @LordWilmore mentioned but first answer seems to be the most appropirate equivalent because you cannot chenge the pointing address.

Comment: None are the same thing but I would say that `f` is the pointer equivalent because the variable being pointed to can be changed (its not const) but the pointer itself can not be bound to another address (it is const).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing here is that reference can not be assigned to point to another object once initialized. So the closest analogy to pointers would be a constant pointer to non-constant object. Thus you just need to find an expression which matches:

```
const *long c = &a; // invalid
const long *d = &a; // non-const pointer to const long
const * long e = &a; // invalid
long *const f = &a; // const pointer to non-const long
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Invalid syntax.
2. Pointer to constant object. The pointer address can change, data cannot.
3. Invalid syntax.
4. The last one is a constant pointer to non-constant object. Like a reference to non-const.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check that code:

```
  long a = 1234; // you declare variable and initialize with 1234 value
  long &b = a;   // you declare another variable that points to the same address as a
```

In that case if you print both you will see that both has the same address and value:

```
  a = 555;
  printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", a, &a, b, &b); \\ a and b are 555
```

But you cannot change the address of b (of a also). Taking all of the above into account you can assume that the fourth option is correct answer as you also cannot change the address of this pointer.

```
  long *const f = &a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all of you forget to mention the principle of C declaration: you should read it from right to left unless it is surrounded by parenthesis.

```
const *long c // c is a long of const pointer, wtf?
const long * d // d is a pointer to a const long, good
const * long e // space doesn't matter in C
long * const f // f is a const pointer to long, good
```